# How to install gcc 4.4.7 on Mountain Lion

Tags: c, macos, gcc, terminal

I need to install a specific version of the GNU GCC compiler, gcc 4.4.7, on my macbook, but I'm not sure how to do this. Most places I've found install later versions but I need to install that specific version. How do I do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) for this.

then

```
brew install gcc44
```

since it will install this specific gcc 4.4.7 version

```
$ brew info gcc44 gcc44: 
  stable 4.4.7
```